# Vagrant Provision to Update to PHP 5.4 on Ubuntu 12.04 Only Works If Applied Manually

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant, ubuntu-12.04

Using Vagrant with Ubuntu 12.04 I've tried provisioning using the Shell multiple ways on a new repository the most recent was this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y php5
```

It appears I can do this manually, but the only diff I can see is I can `press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel` when prompted during addition of ppa, and then running the upgrade asking for a new install of grub.  Is there a way to have the script confirm install of ppa and during upgrade skip grub, or do whatever is needed without causing issues during provisioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have `-y` flag when installing package, you can do

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable

Options:   
  -y, --yes             Assume yes to all queries
```